# What is the indicator in vimrc for when using vim as git mergetool?

Tags: vim

I would like to make some specific settings in vimrc for then I use vimdiff as git mergetool. Normal vimdiff has an indicator `&diff` but it doesn't seem to work for the mergetool setup.

What is the vimrc indicator for when in the *mergetool* filemode?

Comment: If you have configured either `vimdiff` or `gvimdiff`, `:set diff` should be on in the merge buffers (but not any other buffers you might have edited).

Comment: Yes you are right. I must have made something strange before. Now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, great! I've added an answer (with more alternatives) for you to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured either `vimdiff` or `gvimdiff`, `:set diff` should be on in the merge buffers (but not any other buffers you might have edited).

Other means to detect would be:

- checking the number and paths of the command-line arguments via `argc()` and `argv()`
- passing a variable to Vim: `vim -c 'let g:isDiff = 1'`; note that you need to define a custom Git mergetool if you go this route